# Compare dates in SQL statement

Tags: sql-server, select

I'm trying to use the following statement to check if the order is late, but it causes syntax error. How can I write it ?

```
select (enddate > targetdate ) as late from orders
```

Comment: `SELECT enddate, targetdate FROM orders WHERE enddate > targetdate` ?

Comment: No, I want to return flag in order to the compression

Comment: No, I want to return flag in order to the compression

Comment: What are you going to do with this flag? If it's only for display purposes, it's OK. If you want to use this flag for filtering though, it would be faster to handle late entries separately.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're searching something similar to `case` expression:

```
select 
    case 
        when enddate > targetdate then 1 
        else 0 
    end as late
from orders
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need `case`

```
select 
    case 
        when enddate > targetdate then 'enddate  is greater' 
        else 'targetdate is greater' 
    end as late
from orders
```